# The operator < is undefined for the argument type

Tags: java, types, arguments, undefined, operator-keyword

No hate on my Java programming teacher, but I've had some experience with programming, and for the first project I'd like to wow the teacher. Anyways, I'm new to Java, but have some strong knowledge of C.  Just to test out the array system in Java I have designed this program.  What I want it to do is ask me for the size of the array. I need the size of the array, because later I'm going to fill it with the names of the employees.  But I keep getting this error...

```
package withholding_calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

class withholding_calculator {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //declaring variables
    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] employeeNames = new String[size.nextInt()];

    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( employeeNames[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: size is a Scanner object. How could an int be lower than a Scanner? Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. And learn to name your variables correctly: you're confusing yourself by naming a Scanner `size`. And Classes in Java are conventionally CamelCased: `WithholdingCalculator`.

Comment: Just a point : Your class name should start with an UpperCase alphabet. Prefer `WithholdingCalculator` or `Withholding_calculator`  over `withholding_calculator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points to make in response to this.

Firstly, your for loop can use the array size directly (`employeeName.length`) rather than referring to the scanner object (the error is caused by you comparing a scanner to an int).

Secondly, 'c' style arrays are used much less in Java than in C. Typically a Java programmer would code this as:

```
List<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<>();
// fill the list using employeeNames.add
for (String name: employeeNames)
    System.out.println(name);
```

In Java 8 the final 2 lines can be substantially simplified to:

```
employeeNames.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Having said that it is still perfectly reasonable to use standard arrays and your code should function if you compare to the array's length rather than your scanner.

Comment: A Java 8 programmer might write it like that, earlier versions would use `for (String employee : employeNames) { ... }`

Comment: @sprinter if the OP is learning arrays, I think it's a bit too early to go with generics and lambdas. Not sure why you would need a variable to store the array length, since every array has a length: `employeeNames.length`.

Comment: @JBNizet I disagree on the 'bit too early' comment - I actually think they simplify the language if they are learnt early. Functional programming is really pretty natural - it's only old-timers (like me) who find them hard! But you're right on the array length - I'll change my answer.

Comment: @sprinter They become natural when you understand you can pass an object (or a function in this case) to a method, and when you can decrypt error messages. The OP still doesn't understand what "the operator < is undefines for the argument type" means. And anyway, even if arrays are seldomly used, any Java programmer must know them.

Comment: @JBNizet yes fair point. Though I do think List is easier to understand for this type of problem.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve by writing this code is filling an array with a string of names. And I need the user to input how many employees they have, and then after that the names of each employee.  I think I can handle it from there, but the syntax is different from C, in which I could write the entire program in about 20 minutes. Thank you, sprinter!